# How to open a file with exclusive file access in node?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

On Windows, I am looking for a way to open a file with exclusive access. The MSDN documents a function called [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) with `dwShareMode` of `0`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea

In specific I am looking for a way the documentation states here:

> Prevents other processes from opening a file or device if they request delete, read, or write access.

Does anyone know a built-in or **npm** package wrapping this functionality?

Comment: It does not appear that such functionality is supported on Windows in nodejs.  While all the desired flags exist for `fs.open()` in the `mode` argument, the doc says that the bits that control what access others may have is not implemented on Windows.  So, for some module to implement this, they'd have to implement their own entire file system access without depending on `fs.open()` at all which I have never seen.  Why this is not implemented on Windows, I have no idea as the underlying OS certainly contains the desired functionality.

Comment: Let me revise my previous comments.  It's possible that exclusive access is supported using [fs-ext](https://github.com/baudehlo/node-fs-ext).  There's lots of chatter from a few years ago in the bugs about it not working on Windows, but now the issue is marked as resolved so maybe it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module add-on `fs-ext` will work on Windows if you can build it successfully.  I had to install Python on my system and put it in the path before it would install and build successfully.  Once I did that, then I was able to run this test which verified that a child process was not allowed to read or write to a file that I had an flock on:

```
// open-exclusive.js
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;
const child = require('child_process');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const execP = promisify(child.exec);
const flock = promisify(require('fs-ext').flock);

const exclusive = fs.constants.S_IRUSR | fs.constants.S_IWUSR | fs.constants.S_IXUSR;

async function run() {
    const fHandle = await fsp.open("./temp.txt", "r+", exclusive);
    await flock(fHandle.fd, 'ex');
    await fHandle.write("Goodbye", 0);
    console.log('parent finished write');

    const { stdout, stderr } = await execP("node open-exclusive-child.js");
    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
    console.error('stderr:', stderr);
    console.log('parent done exec');
    await fHandle.close();
    return "good";
}

run().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

And the child process file open-exclusive-child.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;

async function run() {
    const fHandle = await fsp.open("./temp.txt", "r");
    let buf = Buffer.alloc(10);
    await fHandle.read(buf, 0, 10, 0);
    await fHandle.write("Hello", 0);
    console.log('child: finished write');
    await fHandle.close();
    return "child good"
}

run().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

When I run `node open-exclusive.js`, the parent will open it, flock it successfully and then the child will not be able to read or write to the file.  The child is apparently allowed to "open" the file, but gets an EBUSY error when trying to read or write to it.

In fact, the flock works in the same process too:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;
const { promisify } = require('util');
const execP = promisify(child.exec);
const flock = promisify(require('fs-ext').flock);

const exclusive = fs.constants.S_IRUSR | fs.constants.S_IWUSR | fs.constants.S_IXUSR;

async function run() {
    const fHandle = await fsp.open("./temp.txt", "r+", exclusive);
    await flock(fHandle.fd, 'ex');
    await fHandle.write("Goodbye", 0);
    console.log('parent finished write');

    const fHandle2 = await fsp.open("./temp.txt", "r");
    const buf = Buffer.alloc(10);
    console.log("About to read from fHandle2");
    let bytes = await fHandle2.read(buf, 0, 10, 0);
    console.log(bytes);
    await fHandle2.close();
    await fHandle.close();
    return "good";
}

run().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

When I run this, I get this in the console:

```
node open-exclusive.js
parent finished write
About to read from fHandle2
[Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, read] {
  errno: -4082,
  code: 'EBUSY',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Comment: That's the perfect answer! I will add a bounty to this afterwards. I could compile it, and it works here too. Thanks a lot!